# Oracle/SQL: invalid number format model when concatenating a date and a time into a single date value

Tags: sql, oracle, date, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger in Oracle that compares two dates and then deletes records if the difference of the two dates falls below a certain value. I have a full date value with the format 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MI' and then for the second date value, I want to concatenate a 'DD-MON-YYYY' value with a 'HH24MI' value.

The problem I am getting is that when I try to concat the date and time value together using to_char, and then using to_date on that returned value, it gives me a ORA-01481 invalid number format error. The relevant lines from the trigger itself are below. If anyone can help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dateTrig
...
DECLARE
    day date;
    ftime date;
    CURSOR c_table1 IS SELECT ...;
BEGIN
FOR entry IN c_table1 LOOP
    day := to_date(entry.fdate);
    ftime := to_date(to_char(day, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' ' || to_char(entry.dtime, 'HH24MI'), 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MI'); -- this is the line that is causing the error
    dbms_output.put_line(day || ', ' || ftime);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: What's the data type of the DTIME column? Your code assumes it's a date. But I doubt it is.

Comment: DTIME is a varchar(4) that looks like '1600' for 4:00pm, or '1530' for 3:30pm, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since DTIME is not a date type, you cannot use TO_CHAR with a date format. If it's zero padded to a length of 4 characters, you can simplify it like this:

```
ftime := to_date(to_char(day, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' ' || entry.dtime, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24MI');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best to avoid using to_char's if you can and try to stick with functions that return values in their native date formats, this way you may also not need to run a to_date command on your string, you may have some success with the following or a close relation to it:

```
ftime := Trunc(Sysdate) || ' ' || Extract(Hour From entry.dtime) || ':' Extract(Minute From entry.dtime)
```

Best of luck

Comment: I changed my line to one like yours, with no luck. I get a    
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string.

day := to_date(entry.fdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
ftime := day || ' ' || to_date(entry.dtime, 'HH24MI');

Comment: Ah apologies, I wasn't aware that your Dtime was formatted as a varchar, that's why the Extract functions would not work, Codo's answer is the one for this case.